# Проблема с функцией в классе Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, функции

Есть код:

```
class Fractional:
    #create fractional
    def __init__(self, integer, numerator, denomirator):
        self.integer = integer
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denomirator

    def __str__(self):
        if self.numerator != 0:
            return f'{self.integer}({self.numerator}/{self.denominator})'
        else:
            return f'{self.integer}'

    def reduction(self):
        common_factors = []
        factors_numer = []
        factors_denom = []
        denom = self.denominator
        numer = self.numerator
        #looking for numerator prime factors
        i = 2
        while i * i <= numer:
            while numer % i == 0:
                factors_numer.append(i)
                numer = numer / i
            i = i + 1
        if numer > 1:
            factors_numer.append(numer)

        #looking for denominator prime factors
        j = 2
        while j * j <= denom:
            while denom % j == 0:
                factors_denom.append(j)
                denom = denom / j
            j = j + 1
        if denom > 1:
            factors_denom.append(denom)
        #looking for common prime factors
        i1 = 0
        i2 = 0
        while (i1 < len(factors_numer)) and (i2 < len(factors_denom)):
            if factors_numer[i1] > factors_denom[i2]:
                i2 += 1
            elif factors_numer[i1] < factors_denom[i2]:
                i1 += 1
            else: #factors_numer[i1] == factors_denom[i2]
                common_factors.append(factors_numer[i1])
                i1 += 1
                i2 += 1
        #reducting fractions
        for w in common_factors:
            self.numerator = int(self.numerator/w)
        for f in common_factors:
            self.denominator = int(self.denominator/f)
        #transfer to integer part
        while self.numerator >= self.denominator:
                self.numerator -= self.denominator
                self.integer += 1 

    def __add__(self, other):
        sumint = self.integer+other.integer
        sumnumer = self.numerator*other.denominator + other.numerator*self.denominator
        sumdenom = self.denominator*other.denominator
        raw_sum = Fractional(sumint, sumnumer, sumdenom)
        total = raw_sum.reduction()
        print(total)

x = Fractional(100, 128, 64)
y = Fractional(2, 2, 5)
print(x+y)
```

P.s. чтобы вы долго не разбирались, поясню: создаю класс дробей. Функция `reduction()` сокращает те самые дроби. В итоге хочу, чтобы дроби в функции `__add__` складывались и сокращались, поэтому вызываю в `__add__` `reduction()`

проблема выходит в функции `__add__`, а именно: переменная `raw_sum` выводит как надо, я испытал, но, когда вызываю `raw_sum.reduction()`, возвращается `None`, хотя вне кода функции (просто внизу кода), функция `reduction` работает как надо.

В чём моя проблема и как можно пофиксить?

Заранее благодарю

Comment: Функция reduction ничего не возвращает, поэтому вы получаете None. Чтобы получить что-то другое, нужное значение должно возвращаться через return.

Comment: Кстати, НОД находится намного проще, см. [Алгоритм Евклида](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/60131/).

Comment: Точнее, для сокращения дроби не нужно находить все общие простые делители, достаточно просто найти НОД с помощью алгоритма Евклида, потом поделить числитель и знаменатель на него.